# iOS Get Screenshot Of Visible Portion of a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, screenshot

I'm trying to get my app to take a screenshot of a view (a table view). This is the code I use to do this:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tableView.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); //retina display
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tableView.frame.size);
[self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This works, but only if the table view is scrolled to the very top, if it's not, the image is black. The only solutions to this that I have found is for capturing the entire table view. I only need the visible portion. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you try `self.tableView.superview.layer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by changing self.tableView.layer to self.tableView.superview.layer.